# Why are my styles getting removed when I try to print a webpage in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, printing, print-css

I am not able to figure out why my button styles/colors are getting removed when I try to print my webpage. I am using bootstrap for some of my styles. [image: My Webpage]
[image: Print Screen]

```
.button.primary {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 18px;
    line-height: 1.8rem;
    background-color: #EEB111;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: it is a defaut setting on printers(bg-colors/bg-image) are not print ...  to spare ink i guess. Only the user can change this, style sheets have no power upon hardware :( :)

Comment: @GCyrillus - if you notice in the screenshot above those options are selected... so I'm not sure why it is still removing the colors?

Comment: oh yes, then check on the `@media print` rules and removed/comment lines where bg is reset. otherwise `@media only screen` , might be involved, remove `only` to apply all style to `all` (includes `print`)

Comment: create a fiddle for reproducing issue

Comment: @Fawn I've updated my answer. Have you tried to remove the print styles from bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with bootstrap. If your bootstrap [includes print media styles](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_print.scss), because it might be not [customized](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) in a way it excludes them, some styles will get changed.

[image: boostrap with and without print media styles]
*(Hintergrundgrafiken = background graphics)*

**Also this is important**, as you already did correctly in your screenshot:
To print the page with colors and stuff, e.g. in Firefox you have to tell the browser by clicking on `File > Page Setup... > Print background` or `Print (icon in the top right menu) > Page Setup... > Print background`.

Comment: I selected print background, images and colors and it still is showing like the above screenshot :( if you notice in the screenshot above those options are selected.

Comment: Updated my answer. Seems like the problem is in the bootstrap media styles. I created a minimal local example with boostrap and with a customized boostrap (no "Print media styles" included), and it worked for me only with the customized version.

Comment: This fixed my issue when I commented out the bootstrap print styles. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `@media print` for printing those styles e.g.

```
@media print {
  body { font-size: 10pt }
}
```

If not then follow here

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Media
- https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule

Hope this will help you in some way (y).

Comment: I am using print styles, but I haven't added every button style, link style, image style etc to the print style sheet just in my normal styles.css stylesheet. Do I have to define and copy every single style to my print style sheet again?

Comment: I just tried adding my button style to my print.css stylesheet and it still didn't work for me. I'm not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

It is getting removed because css-stylesheets have attribute known as `media` it defines in which media this css file will work.

try to put this on your style sheet `media="all"` or media="print"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Comment: you need to write media="all" in all the css files that you are including in your html page. It does work.

Comment: This did not work for me either. I added it and it is still showing up like the screenshot above.

Comment: Sorry then try media="print" it is working in many other places.

Comment: Sorry, but it won't help here. Media="all" is btw. the default value.